# Why does Location in OnLocationChanged have old time?

Tags: android, xamarin, gps, android-2.3-gingerbread

I listen to location changes with `OnLocationChanged`, I use solely GPS. The problem is with the time values (milliseconds from 1970-01-01). In my case it represents 32 years, so it gives year 2002, I would understand some fluctuations but being off by 19 years is somewhat a big difference.

It is not `long` type capacity, it can express values covering year 2021 and much more.

So what is the reason I get such odd time and how to fix it using GPS time (i.e. without to reverting to simply getting system time)?

*Android 2.3 Gingerbread.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950956/android-onlocationchanged-location-gettime-returns-wrong-time

Comment: @Jason, thank you! Considering it is 5-old question I revert to using system time ;-).